# Duplicity & Google Drive error

Tags: deja-dup, drive, google, duplicity

In order to back up my data, from my Ubuntu 18.04.3 system, I use Duplicity (0.7.17-0ubuntu1.1) and have the back-up stored in Google Drive.
After running, duplicity gives this report:

```
Giving up after 5 attempts. Error: gdata-service-error-quark: Authenticatie verplicht: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
 (4)
```

For the record: in Nautilus I can open the Google Drive folder and see several files saved there with names like "duplicity-full.20200104T112835Z.vol148.difftar.gz". So, it seems to work properly, but just as the case is with back-ups, I want to be 100% sure.

I found many reports on this bug at different fora, but no one can really tell whether there is a problem. Anyone here who can?